# How to use URLClassloader and reflection in OGNL Expression

Tags: java, reflection, struts2, variadic-functions, ognl

I am going to use `URLClassLoader` with OGNL Expression, which will load a remote jar file.
    however,there is an Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callAppropriateMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1244)
    at ognl.ObjectMethodAccessor.callMethod(ObjectMethodAccessor.java:68)
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1349)
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:90)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.ASTChain.getValueBody(ASTChain.java:141)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.ASTAssign.getValueBody(ASTAssign.java:52)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.ASTSequence.getValueBody(ASTSequence.java:63)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
    at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:644)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:702)
    at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:672)
```

here is my code

```
Ognl.getValue("#cl=new java.net.URLClassLoader(new java.net.URL[]{new java.net.URL('http://*.*.*.*/wd.jar')}),#lc=#cl.loadClass('Hello'),#o=#lc.getConstructor().newInstance(),#m=#lc.getDeclaredMethod('hello'),#m.invoke(#o,null)",
```

The Web log shows that `URLClassLoader` has visited the jar file,however,the function which i invoked is not work properly.

```
xxxxxxxx - - [28/Jul/2015:07:19:38 -0400] "GET /wd.jar HTTP/1.1" 200 613 "-" "Java/1.7.0_51" "-"
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the varargs in `getConstructor` and `getDeclaredMethod` methods. OGNL doesn't treat varargs very well.

You can rewrite your expression to avoid varargs. You don't need to call constructor to get a new instance and once you have an instance there is no need to use reflection in OGNL. :)

```java
Ognl.getValue("#cl=new java.net.URLClassLoader(new java.net.URL[]{"
    + " new java.net.URL('http://*.*.*.*/wd.jar')}), #lc=#cl.loadClass('Hello'),"
    + " #o=#lc.newInstance(), #o.hello()", context);
```

BTW is your `Hello` class in the default package? You need to supply FQN in `loadClass` (e.g. `loadClass('some.package.Hello')`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, helped me a lot!

Comment: it works well when I test it in my java project,however,when i test on Struts2 project i found it does not work properly,i debug the Struts2 project,it throws out an exception:"nosuchmethod xxx",i change my code and put the code into construct method,it works well,why is that?thanks

Comment: @iswin: Not sure what do you mean by S2 project and putting the code in constructor.